# Spring batch - how to dynamically increase and decrease threads using ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

Tags: java, concurrency, spring-batch

I'm fairly new to Spring-Batch so this may be a lack of understanding on my part. I'm wanting to understand how to dynamically increase and *decrease* threads using the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor in conjunction with the ThreadPoolExecutor while my job is running.  I've tried to subclass both the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor and the ThreadPoolExecutor so I can gain access to the beforeExecute() and afterExecute() which would allow me to terminate threads if the corepoolsize was decreased using an approach that is listed on this site.

What I seem to be not understanding is that when I override the initializeExecutor() method which returns an ExecutorService, it apparently does not set the (private internal) threadPoolExecutor variable in the parent class (ThreadPoolTaskExecutor). It sets the private ExecutorService executor; (from the ExecutorConfigurationSupport class)

Since the threadPoolExecutor is not a protected member I cannot gain access to it.  Without that being set, when I run I obviously end up getting a "ThreadPoolExecutor not initialized" error within the Spring Framework when I examine what's wrong under the covers.

public class MyThreadPoolTaskExecutor extends ThreadPoolTaskExecutor
{

```
@Override
protected ExecutorService initializeExecutor(ThreadFactory tf, RejectedExecutionHandler reh)
{

    BlockingQueue <Runnable> queue = createQueue(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    MyThreadPoolExecutor tp_executor = new MyThreadPoolExecutor( this.getCorePoolSize(), this.getMaxPoolSize(),     this.getKeepAliveSeconds(), TimeUnit.SECONDS, queue);

    // if you look at the parent class(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) it performs this call next.
    //  this.threadPoolExecutor = executor;
    // that is a private member with no ability to set via any methods.

    return tp_executor;
}
```

}

public class MyThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor 
{

```
public MyThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maxPoolSize, long keepAliveTimeout, TimeUnit timeunit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, ThreadFactory tf, RejectedExecutionHandler reh) 
{
    super(corePoolSize, maxPoolSize, keepAliveTimeout, timeunit, workQueue, tf, reh);
}

protected void beforeExecute (final Thread thread, final Runnable job) 
{   
  ...
}
```

}

Can someone explain what I am missing in my approach?

Comment: Why are you trying to dynamically change the amount of threads you're running?

Comment: We have a multitude of jobs running on our production boxes. If capacity were to free up on a box for a window of time our prod support may want to throw more threads at a job for some period of time. The ability to dynamically increase and/or decrease threads for a period of time can be a useful tool for prod support when there is a lot of activity on a box.

Comment: This sounds like a solution for dynamic resource management. How are you determining that more resources are available or are you guys trying to change amount of threads on the fly?

Comment: Our prod support team utilizes tooling and if available cpu's become available they would want to increase the # of threads for this job on the fly to achieve maximum throughput.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to use one number of threads in one job step and another number of threads in another job step. Simple way to achieve that would be to declare two separate executors with necessary number of threads, zero `corePoolSize` (to not create threads when this is not necessary) and zero `keepAliveSeconds` (to not keep threads when this is no longer necessary). Then just inject first executor in one step and second executor in another step.

```
@Configuration
public class Conf {

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor executorA(@Value("${first.number.of.threads}") int numberOfThreads) {
        return executor(numberOfThreads);
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor executorB(@Value("${second.number.of.threads}") int numberOfThreads) {
        return executor(numberOfThreads);
    }

    private TaskExecutor executor(int numberOfThreads) {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(0);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(numberOfThreads);
        executor.setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
        executor.setKeepAliveSeconds(0);
        return executor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly. I could have a step that has to process a few hundred thousand records, so even with tasks that execute rather quickly this could take quite awhile to accomplish. With tons of jobs running on our box, there could be windows of time with less activity so we want to increase the number of threads for some period of time ( same step ). I'm wanting a dynamic tuning capability for production support so they can increase and/or decrease threads for a given step.

Comment: I believe this is already managed by the ThreadPoolExecutor. I'm looking over some documentation and will try to get back to you

Comment: @EdT it seems that you can define max pool size to meet your high activity requirements and core pool size to meet your minimal activity requirements (could be 0) and then set non-zero keep alive seconds to allow threads to be automatically shutdown back to core pool size when there is no activity.

Comment: increasing threads works fine and they are dynamically added, but decreasing the  core pool size does NOT automatically shut them down. It appears that you have to specifically perform that task yourself.  Trying to obtain that actual hook to perform that task is what spawned my question and why I shared the code above.

Comment: I was talking about specifying corePoolSize=5, maxPoolSize=10 and keepAliveSeconds=7. Then by default pool will have 5 threads. If there is enough tasks it will grow up-to 10 threads in size. Threads 6-10 will be automatically stopped after 7 second of inactivity thus pool will resume to size 5 when there is not enough tasks.

Comment: I wonder if you're providing enough tasks for your threadpools. Throwing more threads at the problem doesn't necessarily make it solve any faster when there's only so many tasks available to process.